# AngularJS ng-repeat list with buttons: Disable button after click

Tags: angularjs, list, button

I have in AngularJS a list with multiple entries and for each entry a button. When clicking the button, the application will do some stuff and after that was successful, the button should be disabled.

The interesting part in my template look like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
  <span>{{item}}</span>
  <button ng-click="doSomeStuff(item)">Request</button>
</li>
```

I already tried to use the ng-if directive, but then of course every button will disappear.

Previously, I thought about a solution in raw Javascript or jQuery, because it is very easy just to modify the button by its id. But is there a solution provided by AngularJS?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ng-disabled` as follows:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
  <span>item</span>
  <button ng-click="doSomeStuff(item)" ng-disabled="item.disabled">Request</button>
</li>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.doSomeStuff = function(item) {
    //do operations and finally set disabled to true for that button
    item.disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Looks like a good solution, although I merge model data with ui. But for me it works. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer if you found it correct... :)

Comment: How do I do that? I'm quite new to StackOverflow :D

Comment: Haha...Click the tick underneath the down arrow on the left.

Comment: Done. Thanks again :)